# Get duplicate rows in different table mysql

Tags: mysql, duplicates, sql-insert, sql-delete

I have a table named 'Student' with columns 'Name' and 'Roll Number'

```
name Roll_Number
    A   1
    A   2
    A   1
    B   2
    B   2
    C   3
    C   2
    D   4
```

I want to delete all the rows from this table having same name but different Roll_number and insert those rows in new table 'Temp'. So after operation Both tables should be like this

Table Student

```
 name Roll_Number
    B   2
    B   2
    D   4
```

Table Temp

```
 name Roll_Number
    A   1
    A   2
    A   1
    C   3
    C   2
```

Because A and C, both have different values for Roll_Number column, So we delete all the entries of A and C from Student table and add it to Temp Table

So how this can be done through mysql query?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

For Student table:

```
SELECT name, Roll_Number
FROM Student
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Roll_Number) = 1
```

For Temp table:

```
SELECT name, Roll_Number
FROM Student
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Roll_Number) > 1
```

Comment: While executing the query, I am getting only one single row for A and C in the Temp table and only one row for B and D in Student table

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query to insert *all* records which, for a given `name` have more than one `Roll_Number`, into a new temporary table `Temp`:

```
INSERT INTO Temp (name, Roll_Number)
SELECT name, Roll_Number
FROM Student
WHERE name IN (SELECT name
               FROM Student
               GROUP BY name
               HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Roll_Number) > 1)
```

And here is a query to delete these same records from `Student`:

```
DELETE FROM Student
WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM Temp)
```

Note that I did the insertion into the new table first before deleting them from the old table (for obvious reasons).

Comment: Your first query worked. While running second query I got the error ''You can't specify target table 'Student' for update in FROM clause'' . Then I used the Temp table in Select statement of second query and I get the desired result.

Thanks for help

Comment: In first glance, it looked that insert query is working fine. But it picks few records that are not required. So I have posted a query by modifying your query with Tim query and I get the desired result. Thanks for Help

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query that work for me, created from `SMA` and `Tim` answers.
For inserting into Temp Table

```
INSERT INTO Temp (name, Roll_Number)
SELECT name, Roll_Number
FROM Student
WHERE name IN (SELECT name
FROM Student
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Roll_Number) > 1);
```

Deleting record query is same as mentioned by `Tim`

```
DELETE FROM Student
WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM Temp)
```

Thanks to both of them